# How to overwrite a file in specific folder with a file in my program's resources

Tags: vb.net, file, path, copying

I have a file named "something.a binary extension" "not a txt extension" in my program's resources and the same file exists in another folder and named "Something.a binary extension" too.

I want to copy my resources file and replace the existing file with it.

My program has 2 `button` controls, one for browsing to get the `path` from `OpenFileDialog1` and the other to copy my resources file and replace the existing file "Which have the same name" by it, and 1 `TextBox` to display the `path`.

[image: Program Photo]

My program has a manifest file to run as Adminstrator with `level="highestAvailable`.

I use this code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim Path_of_folder As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        'getting the path
        OpenFileDialog1.ValidateNames = False
        OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = False
        OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "somthing.exe"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("somthing.exe", "").Trim()
        Path_of_folder = TextBox1.Text 'we got the path
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCopy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCopy.Click
        FileCopy(My.Resources.somthing, Path_of_folder) ' this got Error when i use it,  but the program can Run 
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The issue many beginners have is they don't know how to break a problem down into parts. SO requires that each question relate to a single problem and yet you have asked us three separate things there. Reading resource data is one topic, selecting a file path is an completely independent topic and writing to a file is a third completely independent topic. You need to research each of those three topics independently and try to implement each yourself first. If you encounter an issue, then you can ask a question about that specific issue alone. It's problem-solving 101: divide and conquer.

Comment: with my all respect to you , i have worked on this project for 5 days and all what i get somethings don't give any help to me, i just hope for help from someone who know my problem and really hope to help me

Comment: The reason you're not getting help is because, as I said, you are looking at too broad a problem. It's like expecting to get a single answer when asking how to build a house when there are many separate steps and skills involved. If you're not prepared to break the problem down into parts and address each part separately then you're going to continue to encounter the same frustration. There's a right way and a wrong way to approach a programming problem. If you insist on doing it the wrong way then you'll be disappointed with the results. Make the effort to do it right and you'll get help.

Comment: If you've worked on the problem for five days, then you should have some additional details on what you've already tried and how it's failing.  You'll get more and better help if you provide that information to us.

Comment: ok i will sperate it into problems and i will show more details, thanks guys

Comment: I Edited and Added So Many Usefull Information , @jmcilhinney

Comment: @Craig please view my edit :)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Part of your post describes copying data FROM a resource TO a file in a folder. Part of your post describes copying data FROM a file in a folder TO a resource. So, which is it exactly? Because the first is very doable, and the second is not possible without exiting your program to do the copy in another process.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_), eg `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Path_of_folder, "something.txt"), My.Resources.somthing)`, assuming `My.Resources.somthing` is a `String` resource.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm Glad to Find your Respond , Actually i want to copying Data from my program Resources To a folder in my pc . 
this is small example  about what i need :  [File in program] Copied "OverWrite" --> on another File in a [Folder]

Comment: @RemyLebeau i don`t want to use Txt files i want another extition . 
the extition that i want is : File.REZ

Comment: @EslamAlawy I already answered this in my previous comment

Comment: ok i will try it <3 @RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau The Code have Errors although i tried with it and the Type of my Files is not text it is Binary

Comment: @RemyLebeau View GItter

Comment: @EslamAlawy if `My.Resources.somthing` is not a `String`, then what is it exactly? If `UnmanagedMemoryStream` then you can create a `System.IO.FileStream` for `something.txt` and then use `My.Resources.somthing.CopyTo()` or equivalent to copy the resource data to the file stream.

Comment: @EslamAlawy please re-read what I wrote in my previous comment, I addressed that

Comment: @RemyLebeau You solve My Problem please View Gitter first <3